# Как не хардкодно расширить прозрачный DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, dialogfragment

Имеется прозрачный DialogFragment.

```
public class TempFragment extends DialogFragment {

    static TempFragment newInstance() {
        TempFragment dialogFragment = new TempFragment();
        return dialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_block_dialog, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        final Drawable drawable = new ColorDrawable(-15108398);
        drawable.setAlpha(200);

        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1500);
    }
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/block_dialog_layout"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Click"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</LinearLayout>
```

В этих строках:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(1000, 1500);
```

я хардкодингом расширяю `DialogFragment`, так как этого не сделать он получается очень узкий. Как же правильно расширить `DialogFrgment` (не хардкодно) - чтобы он получился такой же как в этом коде, то есть занимал почти весь экран, но оставляя рамки, как и пристало нормальному Диалогу (с Title)).

Может делать так , как сам `DialogFragment` расширяет (когда Title не удаляется пользователем)?

Мне он нужен без титла, я его удаляю `dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` при этом Dialog сужается по максимуму...

Answer (score 2):

Можно получить размер экрана устройства и использовать его для размеров фрагмента

```
Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(size.x, size.y);
```

Также можно показывать фрагмент в активити, для которого в манифесте:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```